# The same code not running on two different hardware in opengl

Tags: c++, glm-math

The code runs successfully on rtx2060 but not on rtx 3060. It uses the same glm library, but it shows a black screen on rtx 3060 and normal screen on rtx2060

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

// GLM Mathematics
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"


GLint Width{ 400 }, Height{ 600 }, NumChannels;
glm::mat4 transform;
glm::mat4 view;

void GetLastError();
void KeyPressedCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
void OnResize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);


int main()
{
    if (GLFW_FALSE == glfwInit())
    {
        GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    GLFWwindow* windowPtr = glfwCreateWindow(Width, Height, "???-----))(((", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (windowPtr == nullptr)
    {
        GetLastError();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowPtr);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "glewinit failed";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetKeyCallback(windowPtr, KeyPressedCallback);


    const GLchar* VertexShaderCode
    {
        "#version 330 core \n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 position; \n"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord; \n"
        "uniform mat4 projection; \n"
        "uniform mat4 model; \n"
        "uniform mat4 view; \n"
        "out vec2 texCoord \n;"
        "void main() \n"
        "{ \n"
        "   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f); \n"
        //"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f); \n"
        "   texCoord = TexCoord; \n"
        "} \n"
    };


    const GLchar* FragmentShaderCode
    {
        "#version 330 core \n"
         "out vec4 color; \n"
         "in vec2 texCoord; \n"
         "uniform sampler2D imageData; \n"
         "void main() \n"
         "{ \n"
         "  color = texture(imageData, texCoord); \n"
        //"  color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); \n"
        "} \n"
    };


    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &VertexShaderCode, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar info[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, nullptr, info);
        std::cout << "Error Info on vertex shader: " << info;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &FragmentShaderCode, 0);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar info[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, nullptr, info);
        std::cout << "Error info of fragment shader: " << info;
    }


    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar info[512];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, info);
        std::cout << "Error info of shader program: " << info;
    }

    //GLfloat vertices[]
    //{
    //    //vertices          //tex coordinates
    //    -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    //    -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
    //    0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    //    0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,

    //    //vertices            //tex coordinates
    //    -0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    //    -0.8f,  0.8f, -0.8f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
    //     0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    //     0.8f,  0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 1.0f,



    //};

    GLfloat vertices[]
    {
        //vertices          //tex coordinates
        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //front

        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //left

        -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  //top

        0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,  1.0f, 1.0f,    //right

        -0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f,  1.0f, 1.0f,    //back
       
        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, -0.8f,  1.0f, 1.0f,    //bottom


    };

    //this messes the texture
    //GLuint indices[]
    //{
    //    0, 1, 2,
    //    2, 1, 3, //front face

    //    0, 1, 4,
    //    4, 1, 5, //left face

    //    4, 5, 6,
    //    6, 5, 7, //back face

    //    2, 3, 6,
    //    6, 3, 7, //right face

    //    1, 5, 3,
    //    3, 5, 7, //top face

    //    0, 4, 2,
    //    2, 4, 6, // bottom face

    //};

    GLuint indices[]
    {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 1, 3,         
    };

    GLint img_width, img_height, img_comps;
    const unsigned char* img_pix = stbi_load("bg.jpg", &img_width, &img_height, &img_comps, STBI_rgb);
    std::cout << "Image width {" << img_width << "}, image heigth {" << img_height << "}, imgage components {" << img_comps << "} " << std::endl;

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img_width, img_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_pix);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(windowPtr, OnResize);
    
    //transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.1f, 0.0f));   
    //transform = glm::rotate(transform, 180.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    
    
    view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));

    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)Width / (GLfloat)Height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    GLint projectLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
    //glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(windowPtr))
    {
        //no need to get uniform location of sampler2D as there is only one, so it automatically binds
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        
        
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");        
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");

        
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

        
        //std::cout << "Transform : " << ;

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(windowPtr);

    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void GetLastError()
{
    const char* error;
    glfwGetError(&error);
    std::cout << error;
}

void KeyPressedCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if ((key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        //std::cout << "Escape Key Pressed \n";
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {                
        view = glm::rotate(view, 15.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    }

    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_RIGHT) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        view = glm::rotate(view, -15.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    }

    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_UP) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        view = glm::rotate(view, -15.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        view = glm::rotate(view, 15.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_W) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {                
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f));
    }
    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_S) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.1f));
    }
    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_A) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(-0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    else if ((key == GLFW_KEY_D) && (action == GLFW_PRESS))
    {
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
}

void OnResize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Ideally it should produce the same output, but it is not.

What is the error here?

Comment: Try checking for open gl errors

Comment: It is not showing any error, it runs but with black screen

Comment: It won't show any errors because you're not checking for them, see https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to believe me that the current code may generate some sensible output due to this line:

```
view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
// which combines matrix as follows: view * translationMatrixBasedOnVec(0,0,-3)
```

where

```
view
```

is initialized by mat4 default constructor - all matrix's components are 0. So any vertex position generated by vertex shader is (0, 0, 0, 0).

If you want to position camera at (0,0,0) , `view` matrix must be identity. What can be achived by

```
glm::mat4 view(1.f)
```

Comment: @KshitijTripathi I seem to recall that in older versions of `glm` the `mat4` default constructor actually did generate the identity matrix (0.9.8.5 and earlier?). So it's possible the two different boxes are just using different `glm` versions.

Comment: glm::identity<glm::mat4>() exists.